# Cadastro N para N (muitos para muitos), onde preciso enviar conforme a imagem um Array

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, padrão-dao

[image: Modal Que Será Enviado Para Servlet.]

Estou fazendo um cadastro N para N (muitos para muitos), onde preciso enviar conforme a imagem um Array de medicamentos, Unidade e posologia. A questão é como pegar esse Array em apenas um request e persistir na DAO na tabela com esse array. Isso é possível, pois na DAO como vou cadastrar um array percorrendo cada coluna da tbela e dando os insert no JAVA.

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------CONTROLLER

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
Integer idAnimal = (Integer) session.getAttribute("idAnimal");
String obsRecAnimal = request.getParameter("observacao_receituario_animal");
String dataEmissaoRec = request.getParameter("data_emissao_receituario_animal");
String medAnimal = request.getParameter("medicamento_animal");
String unidDoseAnimal = request.getParameter("unidade_dose_medicamento_animal");
String posologiaAnimal = request.getParameter("posologia_receituario_animal");


Animal animal = new Animal();
ReceituarioAnimal receituario = new ReceituarioAnimal();
receituario.setDataEmissaoReceituarioAnimal(Conversoes.converterData((dataEmissaoRec).replace("-", "/")));
receituario.setObservacaoReceituarioAnimal(obsRecAnimal);
receituario.setMedicamentoAnimal(medAnimal);
receituario.setUnidadeDoseMedicamentoAnimal(unidDoseAnimal);
receituario.setPosologiaReceituarioAnimal(posologiaAnimal);
animal.setIdAnimal(idAnimal);
receituario.setAnimal(animal);
```

---

DAO

```
public Integer cadastrar(ReceituarioAnimal recAnimal) throws Exception {

    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Integer idReceituarioAnimal = null;
    String sql = "INSERT INTO receituarioanimal(data_emissao_receituario_animal, "
            + "medicamento_animal, unidade_dose_medicamento_animal, id_animal, "
            + "observacao_receituario_animal, "
            + "posologia_receituario_animal) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) RETURNING id_receituario_animal;";
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        stmt.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(recAnimal.getDataEmissaoReceituarioAnimal().getTime()));
        stmt.setString(2, recAnimal.getMedicamentoAnimal());
        stmt.setString(3, recAnimal.getUnidadeDoseMedicamentoAnimal());
        stmt.setInt(4, recAnimal.getAnimal().getIdAnimal());
        stmt.setString(5, recAnimal.getObservacaoReceituarioAnimal());


        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            idReceituarioAnimal = rs.getInt("id_receituario_animal");
        }
```

Comment: Olá @felipe bem vindo ao StackOverflow, por favor adicione a sua pergunta a estrutura das tabelas do banco de dados

Comment: Também é interessante que verifique os métodos que passou na seção "Controller" e "Dao" para verificar se não está faltando nenhuma parte importante pois, apararentemente, os trechos que colocou estão muito cortados